# How can I add a background image to the bottom tab bar in a Xamarin Forms Shell application with an iOS renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know how to do this in the top header area:

```
    protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
    {
        var renderer = base.CreateShellSectionRenderer(shellSection);
        if (renderer != null)
        {
            (renderer as ShellSectionRenderer).NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("LaunchIcon.png"), UIBarMetrics.Default);

        }
        return renderer;
    }
```

but not in the bottom navigation tab area.

Would appreciate any advice from anyone who has tried to customise the bottom area background.

Comment: Are you trying to setup each icon of the tab? Isn't that something already available in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0):

In IOS **ShellRenderer** , you can override `IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker` to set background image to TabBar.

```
protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
{
    return new MyOtherShellTabBarAppearanceTracker();
}

void IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker.SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(controller,appearance);
        var tabBar = controller.TabBar;
        UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("TabBackground.png"); // tab bar background image
        tabBar.BackgroundImage = image;
        tabBar.ClipsToBounds = true;// if needed. If image is larger than the tab bar, the tab bar will expand to the image size. With this the image will be clipped to the tab bar size.
    }
}
```

[image]